# top viewed from last week

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fetch the videos that top viewed from the last week, 
my client has the following table :

```
CREATE TABLE `videos` (  
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    `album` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
    `name` varchar(225) NOT NULL,  
    `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  
    `uploading_user` int(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2715',  
    `host` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
    `host_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  
    `active` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
    `featured` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
    `date_added` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',  
    `view` int(125) NOT NULL,  
    `rating` int(125) NOT NULL,  
    `rating_count` int(125) NOT NULL,  
    `category` varchar(225) NOT NULL,  
    `genre` varchar(225) NOT NULL,  
    `playlist` varchar(225) NOT NULL,  
    `video_image` varchar(225) NOT NULL,  
    `votecount` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,  
    `banner_image` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'IB_header_solo4.jpg',  
    `bg_image` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'IB_bck_hd_sect.jpg',  
    `bg_color` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '#000000',  
    `user_video` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
    `description` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,  
    `country` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,  
    `city` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,  
    `location` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,  
    `reported` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1531 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

in this table `date_added` field for on which date we have added this video,
and i have updated the table on every video view in the `view` field, means i have the total views of the particular video.

now what i want, how can i fetch the result of top views videos from last week?
can i have to add another date field on which i add the id of the viewed videos?
or any other alternate solution?

Comment: Do you understand how to select videos from last week? Do you know how to select the top videos?

Comment: *"how can i fetch the result of top views videos from last week?"* - do you mean videos *added* last week, or videos *viewed* last week?

Comment: @MarkBannister video viewed last week, collect last viewed from monday to sunday, and show it on the current.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: @WiiMaxx, i just asking `can i have to add another date field on which i add the id of the viewed videos?`, i stuck here cause might be i was wrong to fetch. i was displayed the viewed result from last 7 days from current date, but client want to display last weekend result on current week.

Comment: @jogesh_pi you are certainly need a separate table where you should save the views per day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get a list of videos with the number of views in the last week, you need to store views separately. The views column in the table would only give you access to the total number of views but it does not give any indication as to when those views were generated.

I would use a table with video_id, datetime and number of views to store the views. By using a DATETIME column and the requirement that the combination video_id and DATETIME is unique, you can store views down to the second and create more statistics later.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's best you keep a separate table to store who viewed the videos, adding it to this table you will be limited with the number of people you can associate as viewers. Regarding your query. It would be better if you keep a seperate field that stores `weekly views`.

assuming you had a field called `week_views`

```
 SELECT required_fields FROM videos ORDER BY week_views DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * (or required fields) FROM videos
WHERE date_added >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) +7 DAY
AND date_added < CURDATE() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY
ORDER BY view DESC
```

Something like that should select the videos from last week, Monday to Sunday (not necessarily last 7 days.)

Comment: do you actually have videos that have views from the last week?

Comment: i've tested it in a similar way... this should be working great

Comment: and Arjan is right with the point that the views will not necessarily come from last week, but you'll be getting the most viewed videos 'now', that were added last week.